# How to unpickle inferSent and load model?

Tags: pickle, torch

I had a working code that simply loads the infersent model. Now, it wont unpickle the model

```
    MODEL_PATH = "./encoder/infersent1.pkl" 
    params_model = {'bsize': 64, 'word_emb_dim': 300, 'enc_lstm_dim': 2048,
                'pool_type': 'max', 'dpout_model': 0.0, 'version': 
    model_version}
    inferSent = InferSent(params_model)
    print(MODEL_PATH)
    inferSent.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH))

use_cuda = False
inferSent = inferSent.cuda() if use_cuda else inferSent
# If infersent1 -> use GloVe embeddings. If infersent2 -> use InferSent 
embeddings.
W2V_PATH = './dataset/GloVe/glove.840B.300d.txt' if model_version == 1 else 
'../dataset/fastText/crawl-300d-2M.vec'
inferSent.set_w2v_path(W2V_PATH)
```

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem is that your pickle file has not been downloaded properly.
Check the size of your file, it should be around 160 MB. For some reason, the links in the infersent repo don't work. You can build your own NLI model using the train_nli.py script provided in the repository. 
python train_nli.py --word_emb_path 'Your word embedding(for example GloVe/fastText)'